# Error: cannot import name 'text_encoding' from 'io' (unknown location)

Tags: python-3.x, virtual-environment

I've been trying to open up a virtual environment. I want to open python from anaconda powershell prompt, but I can't use it in the virtual environment. I have created the environment by using the command:

```
conda create -n hico python=3.9
```

When I open Python:

```
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\io.py", line 54, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'text_encoding' from 'io' (unknown location)
```

Why is there such an error?
How to solve this problem?